# IOS Facebook Login not working after upgrading to Xcode 9.3

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

My application recently started crashing after upgrading Xcode to 9.3 and updating my iPhone. Unfortunately, it gives me very little information when it does crash.

I have set up breakpoints and I know it crashes exactly on the line where I call loginManager.login().

```
/**
 Defines what should happen when the sign in with facebook button is tapped.
 If an error ocurrs, a hud is displayed to the user. If facebook authentication
 is sucessful, firebase authentication is attempted.
 */
@objc func handleSignInWithFBonTapped() {

    hud.textLabel.text = "Signing in with Facebook..."
    hud.show(in: view, animated: true)

    let loginManager = LoginManager()

    loginManager.logIn(readPermissions: [.publicProfile, .email], viewController: self) { (result) in

        switch result {

        case .success(grantedPermissions: _, declinedPermissions: _, token: _):

            self.signIntoFirebase()

        case .failed(let err) :
            print(err)
            Service.dismissHud(self.hud, text: "Error", detailText: "Failed to retrieve user with error: \(err).", delay: 3)

        case .cancelled :
            Service.dismissHud(self.hud, text: "Cancelled", detailText: "Facebook login cancelled", delay: 1)
        }
    }

}
```

Has anyone else experienced this/upgraded to 9.3 with Facebook login still working ok? Any help is appreciated!

Cheers

Comment: Did you try updating the Facebook Login SDK? I had problems as well when updated Xcode and uninstalling and installing the Facebook SDK solved the issue...

Comment: @Felipe Ferri thanks for the suggestion will definitely try it!